# Convert Cases in a String

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to create a function to reverse all cases in a string.  All lower-case letters should be upper-case, and vice versa. For example: reverseCase("Happy Birthday") ➞ "hAPPY bIRTHDAY"

My code below doesn't work. :(

```js
const functionX = X =>
  X === X.toLowerCase() ? X.toUpperCase() : X.toLowerCase();

function reverseCase(string) {
  const letters = string.split('');
  letters.forEach(functionX);
  return letters.join('');
}

console.log(reverseCase('Happy Birthday!'));
```

Comment: You aren't doing anything with the result of `functionX`

Comment: forEach just loops, it does not alter the string/array you are looping over

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) function does not return the output letter even though it executes the `functionX` for each input letter. You need to use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead to return the letters.

Try like this:

```js
const functionX = X =>
  X === X.toLowerCase() ? X.toUpperCase() : X.toLowerCase();

function reverseCase(string) {
  const letters = string.split('');
  return letters.map(functionX).join('');
}

console.log(reverseCase('Happy Birthday!'));
```

Comment: You beat me to the answer, though I'm somewhat surprised to see that functionX implicitly returns a value as it is defined here. I would think it simply converts the casing of `X` without actually modifying or returning a value. Why is it implicitly `return`ing the result of the case modification? I noticed that it doesn't do this (and behaves the way I expect) if `functionX` was declared as a function, as the `reverseCase` function.

Comment: "Why is it implicitly returning the result of the case modification" that's how map is defined to return the output of `functionX`. If you return nothing from  `functionX` then it will be an array of `undefined` values. Not getting the last part tbh

Comment: What I'm saying is, `function test(X) { X === X.toLowerCase() ? X.toUpperCase() : X.toLowerCase(); }` this will not work because `test` does not return a value. However, this `const functionX = X => X === X.toLowerCase() ? X.toUpperCase() : X.toLowerCase();` does work. The second example implicitly returns a value where the first does not. Why?

Comment: @h0r53, it's a property of an arrow function with a single expression and defined like `f = (...) => expression` does return the expression's evaluated value without needing the return keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Hope its clear

```js
function reverseCase(string) {
  const letters = string.split('');
  let resultLetters = letters.map(letter=> {
    let result = letter == letter.toLowerCase() ? letter.toUpperCase() : letter.toLowerCase();
    return result;
  });
  return resultLetters.join('');
}

console.log(reverseCase('Happy Birthday!'));
```